# Is there a rule for enforcing strict comparison (===) using PHP Code Sniffer?

Tags: php, phpcs, phpcodesniffer

As title says. I am looking for a rule similar to eslint's [eqeqeq](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq), but for PHP. I would want to enforce the use of `===`/`!==` instead of `==`/`!=`.

I have tried googling and searched through their repo as well, but unfortunately to no avail. Just wanna ask here if someone knows of a rule that I have missed before I open an issue on Github :)

Answer (score 2):

Try including the `Squiz.Operators.ComparisonOperatorUsage` sniff. It enforces strict type comparisons, including banning the use of `!$foo` in favour of `=== false`.

It also bans implicit true comparisons, so you can't do something like `if ($foo)`, but you can disable that by excluding the `Squiz.Operators.ComparisonOperatorUsage.ImplicitTrue` error code if that it too strict for your standard.

Answer (score 1):

The [Slevomat Coding Standard](https://github.com/slevomat/coding-standard#slevomatcodingstandardoperatorsdisallowequaloperators-) contains a rule specifically for disallowing loose comparison operators.

### Install

Install the coding standard globally through Composer or locally to your project directory.

`composer global require slevomat\coding-standard`

`composer require slevomat\coding-standard --dev`

### Reference

phpcs is often configured through a `phpcs.xml` file. Add a reference to the slevomat coding standard inside this file using the config tag.

```xml
<ruleset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="PHP_CodeSniffer" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="phpcs.xsd">
    <config name="installed_paths" value="{path}"/>
...
</ruleset>
```

The {path} value may be an absolute path if installed globally or a relative path if installed in your project.

`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\slevomat\coding-standard`

`vendor\slevomat\coding-standard`

### Configure

This is an example of a configured phpcs.xml file. I've told phpcs to use the PSR2 rules and also use the DisallowEqualOperators rule from the Slevomat Coding Standard.

```xml
<ruleset ...>
    <config name="installed_paths" value="vendor\slevomat\coding-standard"/>

    <!-- Add your rules below this line -->

    <!-- Use the PSR2 rules that are included with phpcs. -->
    <rule ref="PSR2">

    <!--
        https://github.com/slevomat/coding-standard#slevomatcodingstandardoperatorsdisallowequaloperators-
        Disallows using loose == and != comparison operators. Use === and !== instead, they are much more secure and predictable.
    -->
    <rule ref="SlevomatCodingStandard.Operators.DisallowEqualOperators"/>
</ruleset>
```